# Is there a general method of relation decomposition for any n-ary relation?

Tags: database, entity-relationship, relation

I know that there is a way to decompose a ternary relation into binary relations **[1]**. However, is there a way to either:

- decompose any `n-ary relation` into `m-ary relations` for `m < n`,

Or

- check whether a n-ary relation is in principle decomposable in terms of relations of smaller arity?

I suppose that the answer here is negative. But even if so, how can I justify it ? Can you point me towards some examples ?

**Refrences :** 
**[1]** Song, I. Y., & Jones, T. H. (1995, March). Ternary relationship decomposition strategies based on binary imposition rules. In Proceedings of the Eleventh International Conference on Data Engineering (pp. 485-492). IEEE.

Comment: this is a question for https://cs.stackexchange.com/ ... i think .. you'll find more help there

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried posting it there, but it does not seem to fit any of the followed tags.

Comment: can you share what standards or technologies..  you're using to represent your database , for example uml, merise, sql ..etc .. meaning where do you want to do this

Comment: See [A Comparative Analysis of Entity-Relationship Diagrams](http://www.ischool.drexel.edu/faculty/song/publications/p_jcse-erd.pdf) by Song, Evans and Park (1995). A quote: "...the semantics of a ternary relationship is not always the same as three binary relationships..." As for decomposing n-ary relations, read up on normalization.